# How to select GUID column by another GUID column in VB.net?My Select query does not work

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, select, guid

I am new to programming and get the chance to work and maintain in another developers project.

The project is built with ASP.Net Vb.Net and SQl Server.

I am trying to select the primary key ID (which is actually a GUID) from a table.

```
SQID = Core.DB.GetString("SELECT id FROM SQC WHERE sid = " & sid)
```

In the Table SQC the primary key is id which is guid and the sid is also guid which is primary key to another table.

my previous developer developed the code to select string variable GetString function where GetString is

```
        Shared Function GetString(ByVal selectQueryText As String, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter()) As String
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
        Try
            dt = GetData(selectQueryText, CommandType.Text, params)
            If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Return ""
            Else
                If TypeOf dt.Rows(0)(0) Is DBNull Then
                    Return ""
                Else
                    Return CStr(dt.Rows(0)(0))
                End If
            End If
        Finally
            If dt IsNot Nothing Then dt.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function
```

When I debug the code my process enters into GetString Function and from Get String it goes to GetData function

```
Shared Function GetData(ByVal selectCommandText As String, ByVal selectCommandType As CommandType, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter()) As DataTable
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
        Try
            conn = GetOpenSqlConnection()

            Return GetData(conn, selectCommandText, selectCommandType, params)
        Finally
            If conn IsNot Nothing Then conn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Shared Function GetData(ByVal conn As SqlConnection, ByVal selectCommandText As String, ByVal selectCommandType As CommandType, ByVal ParamArray params As SqlParameter()) As DataTable
        If conn Is Nothing Then Return GetData(selectCommandText, selectCommandType, params)

        Dim sa As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing
        Try
            sa = New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, conn)
            sa.SelectCommand.CommandType = selectCommandType

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Try
                For Each param As SqlParameter In params
                    sa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param)
                Next

                sa.Fill(dt)

                Return dt
            Catch ex As Exception
                dt.Dispose()
                Throw ex
            End Try
        Finally
            If sa IsNot Nothing Then sa.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function
```

In the Try Catch area of exeption handling the code breaks and throws the exception error. It saying **Incorrect syntax near 'a379'**. which is first  the part of sid (GUID). I mean the sid value is **9417A379-6371-432F-9DA5-BCFC46DD95A1**

I am not sure how to handle this. I want to select the id from from SQC table and store it in a variable.

I am looking for your advice and suggestion. As I am new in the programming world please also point me my mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue could be fixed like so:

```
SQID = Core.DB.GetString("SELECT id FROM SQC WHERE sid = '" & sid & "'")
```

But you should be aware that this style of code is open to SQL injection and you may want to look at ways of parameterising your queries (i.e. don't take what's in this project as good practice).

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved my day.

Comment: @Arita - you should really look into SQL injection, particularly if this app contains anything remotely sensitive. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I surely will